# When using <input type="file"> is there any way to populate the input box with some default value?

Tags: php, mysql, image, file

I was using PHP for updating data in Mysql and when I open the update link then if I don't input anything in the file input type then after clicking on the submit button the previously present file/image is not sent.[image of update link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpcfM.png)

But when I input something in input file box in update page then image is uploaded.

Comment: So is the main issue that if it is blank then it sets it to blank in the DB?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Short answer: no.
Longer version: theres no way for you to set a default value for a file-selection. because a file-input points to a file on the local computer (if one was selected). it would be a great security issue if a web dev could f.e. say "make the local passwords file the default value".

you have to handle this another way - default value is not an option for file inputs :)

best,
stefan

Comment: That's not entirely true since about 2017...

Comment: hey, your answer is really helpful. May you suggest any suitable way of passing previous file without updating it.